# Ruby fog installation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fog

I can't figure out how to fix this error. I install libxml2 and nokogiri is also installed properly.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing fog:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... no
-----
libxml2 is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --with-iconv-dir
    --without-iconv-dir
    --with-iconv-include
    --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
    --with-iconv-lib
    --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
    --with-xml2-dir
    --without-xml2-dir
    --with-xml2-include
    --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
    --with-xml2-lib
    --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib
    --with-libxslt-config
    --without-libxslt-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
    --with-libxml-2.0-config
    --without-libxml-2.0-config
    --with-libiconv-config
    --without-libiconv-config


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.5.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.5.10/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Comment: What operating system are you on? How did you install libxml2? There are some instructions that may help here: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to install libxml-devel packages. Every time you see an message like this, if due missing header files from the dependencies. In the installation process it's required to compile native code (C/C++) and to do it the header files are needed.

Answer (score 0):

> libxml2 is missing

You need to install development package for libxml2, e.g.

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

If it still fails, on Ubuntu try installing also:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc ruby-dev libxslt-dev zlib1g-dev
```

See: [Installing Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)